# Proving the range of a blinded value in a Pedersen commitment in zero knowledge

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments, homomorphic-signatures

A prover has the following value:
$$C = (h^ag^x)^b$$

and he needs to prove in zero knowledge to a verifier that $x < t$, for some public threshold $t$.
The verifier knows $h$, $g$, $C$, and $t$. The prover knows everything. Essentially, it is the following relation:

$$\{(a,b,x)\ |\ C = (h^ag^x)^b \wedge x < t\}$$

I know this is possible for a value $s' = h^ag^x$ (using bulletproofs, for example), but I was wondering if it is also feasible given the extra blinding factor $b$. If so, could you explain how or point me to the relevant literature?

Comment: What's the motivation to blind the Pedersen Commitment twice? If your blinding factor $b$ is different between Pedersen Commitments, then they're no longer additively homomorphic

Comment: The blinding factor $b$ is actually the same across different commitments, but it's computed secretly via MPC. I need it to keep the commitments homomorphic and at the same time to prevent a user from tampering with the commitment of another user (e.g. with $C_i \cdot g^{x'}$. In my adversarial model some users are malicious).

Comment: My first thoughts are that I don't think it's possible, because 1. The range proof could only work if $g^b$ is known by verifiers, and 2. Knowledge of $g^b$ allows the commitment tampering that you're trying to prevent. It's possible there is something more elaborate that could solve the problem. Why not just sign the commitments in order to prevent tampering?

Comment: Another possibility is that verifiers take it on trust that a series of commitments to each of the powers of 2 (all blinded by $b$) have been genuinely declared. Those commitments could then be used in range proofs for any commitment blinded by $b$. All provers would need to know the blinding factor $x$ for each of those power-of-2 commitments.

Comment: I can sign each commitment but I also allow any user to add all the commitments together (by multiplying them). Since such user may be malicious, I cannot guarantee that the final commitment is also tamper-free, right?

Comment: I don't fully understand your use case, so I'm not sure why, when a user adds commitments together, that they can't just declare which commitments were added together so that a verifier can check they were correctly added together